# how to change a trial version to a paid version with in app billing android

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

i have a trial version with few things and i wish to convert this into a paid version with in app purchase. How to implement this, please help me with this

Comment: @cavallo-Hey I need to know weather you achieved this or not..?? n if yes then how ??